# Permission issue when uplading a CSV file to a MySQL Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm creating a MySQL 5.7 Docker container and would like to create and populate a database at container startup.

First, the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.7

VOLUME /var/lib/mysql-files

ADD ./scripts/kdd_db_create_tables.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/kdd_db_create_tables.sql
```

Next, the content of `kdd_db_create_tables.sql`:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS cdl;
CREATE DATABASE cdl;
USE cdl;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS kdd;
CREATE TABLE kdd (
   duration BIGINT,
   protocol_type TEXT,
   ..
   class TEXT);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/kdd_dataset.csv' INTO TABLE kdd FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

ALTER TABLE kdd ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Finally, the docker-compose file:

```
---
version: '3.5'
services:
  mysql:
    image: ericsson/mysql5.7:latest
    networks:
      - cdl_net
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    hostname: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql-files
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: cdl
      MYSQL_USER: cdl
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: cdl
      MYSQL_DATABASE: cdl

networks:
  cdl_net:
    driver: bridge
     name: cdl_net
```

The file structure is as follows:

```
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- mysql
    |-- Dockerfile
    |-- data
    |   |-- kdd_dataset.csv
    |-- scripts
        |-- kdd_db_create_tables.sql
```

That is, the SQL script is in `./mysql/scripts`, while the dataset is in `./mysql/data`. Upon container execution, the SQL script is available in the folder `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` in the container, while the dataset is in `/var/lib/mysql-files` (as `LOAD DATA INFILE` requires the file to be in said folder). However, when I run the container, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 13 (HY000) at line 50: File '/var/lib/mysql-files/kdd_dataset.csv' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem seems to be in the way my home is provided by my (internal) infrastructure provider. It is not possible to mount anything in my home :-(

Using /tmp instead

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue here is what i did to resolve this.

**1) The Dokerfile**

```
FROM mysql:5.7

# Add a database
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE abahet

# Add the create.sql to the docker image
# All scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ are automatically
# executed during container startup
COPY ./create.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

# Copy the csv file to /var/lib/mysql-files/ 
COPY ./ratings.csv /var/lib/mysql-files/
```

**2) The container launch script (database.sh)**

```
#!/bin/bash

CMD=$1

IMAGE_TAG=latest

IMAGE_NAME="my-database"

CONTAINER_NAME="my-database"

DATABASE_NAME="test_db"

MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="root"

DATABASE_PORT="3306"

case $CMD in
    build)
        docker build -t  $IMAGE_NAME .
        ;;
    start)
        CMD="docker run"
        CMD="$CMD --rm"
        CMD="$CMD --net=bridge"
        CMD="$CMD --name $CONTAINER_NAME"
        CMD="$CMD -p $DATABASE_PORT:$DATABASE_PORT"
        CMD="$CMD -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
        CMD="$CMD -td $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
        echo "$CMD"
        eval $CMD
        ;;
    init)
        CMD="docker run"
        CMD="$CMD --rm"
        CMD="$CMD --net=bridge"
        CMD="$CMD --name $CONTAINER_NAME"
        CMD="$CMD -p $DATABASE_PORT:$DATABASE_PORT"
        CMD="$CMD -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
        CMD="$CMD -td $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
        echo "$CMD"
        eval $CMD;

        echo "Waiting for mysql start"
        while ! docker exec -it  $CONTAINER_NAME mysqladmin -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD ping &>/dev/null ; do sleep 1 ; done

        sleep 10

        echo "Loading database data"
        docker exec -it $CONTAINER_NAME mysql -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD $DATABASE_NAME -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'var/lib/mysql-files/ratings.csv' INTO TABLE rating FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";

        ;;
    stop)
        docker stop $CONTAINER_NAME
        ;;
    remove)
        docker rm -f $CONTAINER_NAME
        ;;
    rmi)
        docker rmi -f $CONTAINER_NAME
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage : build | start <image_tag> | stop | remove | rmi"
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

3) The usage :

In the Terminal execute the following steps :

```
 #Build the docker image
./database build 

 #Init the container (start + import data)
./database init
```